# Insert Copied Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal is to create an apps script function similar to Excel's Insert Copied Cells. I would like to dynamically select where to paste the copied range with a mouse input similar to how you select cells in a =sum(*Mouse Selection*) formula.

Please help me understand how to select a range with the mouse in order to paste the copied rows in the correct location.

```
function insertCopiedCells() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var copyRange = spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
 var copyRangeRows = copyRange.getNumRows();

 // This is where I want to select the range with a mouse selection

 var pasteRange = spreadsheet.getRange(rangeSelection);
 var pasteRangeRow = pasteRange.getRow();
 pasteRange.activate();
 spreadsheet.insertRowsBefore(pasteRangeRow, copyRangeRows);
 copyRange.copyTo(pasteRange);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to paste there?

Comment: I am pasting a range of cells that are currently selected. I would like the capability to copy any range of cells within the spreadsheet. For the sake of testing, I selected rows 21 through 64 from a sheet inside the spreadsheet.

Comment: So you want that when the user run your script, after writing the formula, he can manualy select where to paste them?

Comment: I want the user select what they want to copy, run the script, manually select where they want to paste it. The script will insert rows as needed, then paste the information in the added rows.

Answer (score 0):

You will need smth like this:

```
function insertCopiedCells() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var copyRange = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
 var data = copyRange.getValues();

 // This is where I want to select the range with a mouse selection
 var cell = Browser.inputBox('Enter the cell address');

 var pasteCell = spreadsheet.getRange(cell)
 var h = data.length;
 var l =  data[0].length;

 spreadsheet.insertRowsBefore(pasteCell.getRow(), h)
 var pasteRange = pasteCell.offset(0, 0, h, l);
 pasteRange.setValues(data);
}
```

Launch it from a custom menu:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Copy Selected', 'insertCopiedCells')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Max, I am looking specifically to be able to select the paste range with a mouse selection rather than keying them in an input box. Is there a different input box with that option?

Comment: Maybe, I missed smth. Here're the refs: [base/prompt-response](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response) and [base/browser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser). No such option in Google Apps Scripts